# Timestamp for global timezone

Tags: flutter, timestamp, timezone

Is there any solution, that I use timezone for example USA, or RUS... for `timestamp`? Because `timestamp.now()` always getting me local time depending the clock of on the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are sample ways to get a timestamp based on date.

`DateTime.now().timeZoneName,` give you the time zone eg *BST*

`DateTime.now()` give you time from your local device  `2020-04-29 16:35:25.138`

`DateTime.now().toUtc()` gives you date time utc Coordinated Universal Time `2020-04-29 15:35:25.139Z`